# What is the best approach in case of JPA with JavaFx application?

Tags: jpa, javafx

I,m writing JavaFx with Hibernate, JPA database engine. I'm really excited about JavaFx property use... unfortunately I don't know how to connect it with JPA. Can anybody recommend good tutorial? Is there is any Hibernate/JPA solutions to automatically generate mapping with JFX properties?

And one more question I did try to user SimpleObjectProperty:

```
myObjectProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
myObjectProperty.set(myObject);
myObjectProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<myObject>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends myObject> ov, myObject t, myObject t1) {
            System.err.println("CHANGE DETECTED");
        }
    });
```

when I'm changing object, change is NOT detected ... any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a decent tutorial to get you started.  It helped me.
http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/48193

Comment: While that link may contain the answer, it is best to include a summary of the salients as well. That way your answer will still be useful - even when the link breaks.

Comment: The above article demonstrates the integration process and MVC aspects of ontegrating JPA and JavaFX, but misses the most important feature of JavaFX: the properties and bindings. So I couldn't suggest as a best practice reference. (I'm still looking for the right answer.)